# How to remove all files with specific extension in folder?

Tags: cmd, terminal

I am looking for command to delete all files with a specific extension in a given folder. Both, for windows and mac.

Thanks!

Comment: Windows: [del /?](http://ss64.com/nt/del.html)

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Delete all files with extension `.tmp` in **current folder**:

*On Windows:*

```
del *.tmp
```

*On Mac:*

```
rm -rf ./*.tmp
```

Delete all files with extension `.tmp` in **current folder Recursively (including sub-folders)**:

*On Windows:*

```
del /s *.tmp
```

*On Mac:*

```
find . -name '*.tmp' -delete
```

Comment: How can I define a similar behavior for a makefile?

Comment: In Windows, `del *.tmp` will delete files with extensions that START with tmp. So `del *.htm` will delete all .htm AND all .html files. I learned that the hard way. On the other hand, the `find . -name "*.ext" -type f -delete` solution from @Spartacvs1 deletes just the specified extension (but recursively, i.e., in all subdirectories, too).

Answer (score 3):

Using the `find` command will do the job efficiently.
Inside the folder, 
`find . -name "*.ext" -type f -delete` 
/!\ - Use this first to know what you are going to delete recursively.
`find . -name "*.bak" -type f`

Also, refer to the `man find` to know more about about it.

Answer (score 1):

Before calling the `del` command you must also change the directory, for example a file bat could be like this

```
cd c:\MyFolderFullOfTmp
del *.tmp
```

Answer (score 1):

you can delete files by using "del" command followed by star
del *.class
del * .txt

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me. I made a small function.

```
empty(){
   cd $1
   rm -rf *
   cd -
}
```

empty PATH/TO/DIRECTORY

You can also use this function.

```
empty(){
   rm -rf $1
   mkdir $1
}
```

empty PATH/TO/DIRECTORY